# foliumにて地図にマッピングしようとすると最大再帰処理回数を超えてしまう。

Tags: python, pandas

GoogleColaboratoryにてfoliumを使用し、地図上にマッピングしたいと考えています。
以下の記事を参照しました。

[Python pandas + folium で Leaflet をもっと使いたい](http://sinhrks.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/12/26/231000)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このようなデータを作成、使用しました。

```
import folium
m = folium.Map(location=[35.861651,139.645435], zoom_start=4.0)
folium.Marker(location=[df_inf.緯度.iloc[0], df_inf.経度.iloc[0]],).add_to(m)
m
```

そして、このようにコードしましたが、どうしても以下の様なエラーが表示されます。

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

本当は以下の様にしてマッピングを行いたいです。

```
for i, row in df_kansen.iterrows():
    m.circle_marker([row['緯度'], row['経度']], radius=(row['p']),
                    popup=row['city'], line_color='#DF5464', fill_color='#EDA098', fill_opacity=0.5)
inline_map(m)
```

どのようにすれば上手く実行されるのでしょうか？
ご教授願います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

参照記事のfoliumの版数が`0.1.6`で現在の最新が`0.10.1`です。
[Folium 0.10.1 documentation](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/)

Google Colaboratoryでサポートしている版数が何かは知りませんが、どこかの記事で版数によってAPIがどんどん変わっているというのを見かけました。
ここですね。
[Folium: Python で地図可視化](https://takaishikawa42.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/01/11/234716)

> ただ、日本語版チュートリアルが少なく、またバージョンが 0.1 とか 0.2 の頃と現在とではマップにピンを置く関数名や使い方が大きく異なっています。余談だと、2017年時点では version0.5 だったのが、2018年に入ってから version0.6 となり、2018年11月に見たら version0.7 になっていました。

`folium.Marker(location=[df_inf.緯度.iloc[0], df_inf.経度.iloc[0]],).add_to(m)`という書き方は最近の仕様だと思われます。

その下の`m.circle_marker(...)`という書き方で動作しているのなら、参照記事に書かれていた`m.simple_marker(...)`に変えれば良いのでは？
参照記事の以下の部分です。

> ```
> m = folium.Map(location=[55, -108], zoom_start=3.0)
> for i, row in df.iterrows():
>     m.simple_marker([row['lat'], row['lon']], popup=row['Name'])
> inline_map(m)
> ```

---

Google Colaboratoryではどうなのかは判りませんが、ローカルな素のPythonの最新環境では、以下の記事を参考に出来ます。
Windows10 1909, 64bit Python 3.8.2, pandas 1.0.3, folium 0.10.1 です。
(記事では発生しているエラーは違いますが)
[AttributeError: 'Map' object has no attribute 'circle_marker'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47615037/9014308)
質問：

> ```
> # add markers
> for geo in geos:
>   tweet_map.circle_marker(location=geo, radius=250)
>
> tweet_map.create
> ```

回答：

> ```
> for geo in geos:
>   #tweet_map.CircleMarker(location=geo, radius=250)
>   folium.CircleMarker(location=geo, radius=250).add_to(tweet_map)
> tweet_map.save('map.html')
> ```

上記を応用して質問記事のコードは以下のようになります。

```
import pandas as pd
import folium

df_inf = pd.read_csv('saitama_covid.csv', header=0)
m = folium.Map(location=[35.861651,139.645435], zoom_start=10.0)

for i, row in df_inf.iterrows():
    folium.Marker([row['緯度'], row['経度']]).add_to(m)
m.save('saitama_marker.html')

for i, row in df_inf.iterrows():
    folium.CircleMarker([row['緯度'], row['経度']], radius=(row['p']),
        popup=row['city'], line_color='#DF5464', fill_color='#EDA098', fill_opacity=0.5).add_to(m)
m.save('saitama_covid.html')
```

ちなみに昨日(04/22)までの分のデータで作ったcsvファイルは以下になります。

```
city,p,緯度,経度
さいたま市,105,35.861651,139.645435
川越市,29,35.925101,139.485793
熊谷市,12,36.14731,139.388645
川口市,83,35.807738,139.724171
行田市,0,36.138949,139.455643
秩父市,2,35.992055,139.084817
所沢市,114,35.799672,139.46861
飯能市,5,35.855731,139.327734
加須市,4,36.131438,139.601719
本庄市,2,36.243568,139.190393
東松山市,0,36.042126,139.399959
春日部市,24,35.975198,139.752301
狭山市,23,35.852942,139.412213
羽生市,2,36.172626,139.548465
鴻巣市,0,36.065758,139.522169
深谷市,7,36.197444,139.281464
上尾市,5,35.977381,139.593206
草加市,25,35.825355,139.805402
越谷市,34,35.891084,139.790938
蕨市,1,35.825634,139.679708
戸田市,20,35.817616,139.677892
入間市,27,35.835766,139.391058
朝霞市,9,35.797252,139.593916
志木市,13,35.83675,139.580319
和光市,17,35.781208,139.605793
新座市,13,35.793511,139.565369
桶川市,2,36.005779,139.542531
久喜市,3,36.061995,139.666838
北本市,0,36.026768,139.530211
八潮市,12,35.822536,139.839175
富士見市,8,35.856759,139.549074
三郷市,8,35.830149,139.872275
蓮田市,4,35.994307,139.662106
坂戸市,0,35.95717,139.402905
幸手市,2,36.078072,139.725861
鶴ヶ島市,8,35.934515,139.393098
日高市,2,35.907796,139.339026
吉川市,0,35.891152,139.841375
ふじみ野市,11,35.879538,139.519764
白岡市,4,36.019026,139.676925
伊奈町,3,36.000112,139.624185
三芳町,4,35.828367,139.526432
毛呂山町,3,35.941501,139.316067
越生町,0,35.964478,139.294199
滑川町,0,36.065987,139.360917
嵐山町,0,36.056655,139.320542
小川町,0,36.056697,139.261845
川島町,2,35.982014,139.481518
吉見町,2,36.039853,139.453728
鳩山町,0,35.981466,139.334101
ときがわ町,3,36.00862,139.296844
横瀬町,0,35.987284,139.100046
皆野町,0,36.07084,139.098754
長瀞町,0,36.114803,139.109717
小鹿野町,0,36.017129,139.008574
東秩父村,0,36.058153,139.194607
美里町,1,36.177104,139.18141
神川町,1,36.213876,139.101776
上里町,1,36.251607,139.144826
寄居町,0,36.118348,139.193012
宮代町,2,36.022682,139.722885
杉戸町,2,36.025765,139.736709
松伏町,0,35.925774,139.815178
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。大変参考になります。緯度経度などのリストを全て`" "`で囲っていたのと取ったところ、正常にマッピングされました。理由は分かりませんが...

Comment: それまでは全て文字列として扱われていたということですね。"を外して人数・緯度・経度が数値として扱えるようになったので正常に動作するようになったのでしょう。

Comment: なるほど。丁寧に説明していただきありがとうございます。